# AsyncDispatch in unmanaged C++ code

Tags: c++, wpf, windows

On C# code, I can do `Application.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(...)` which will fetch the Dispatcher for the application's main thread and invoke a action there.

Is there anyway to do something similar (invoking a function in the main thread) using purely unmanaged C++?

Note that I want to avoid polling techniques.

Comment: [PostMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944.aspx) is one way to run code on a GUI thread. Without knowing what you are really trying to achieve, it's impossible to make any worthwhile suggestions, though.

Comment: PostMessage and PostThreadMessage are definitely what I am looking for. Thank you @IInspectable

Comment: You have to know, when calling `PostThreadMessage` is safe. See [Thread messages are eaten by modal loops](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050426-18/?p=35783) and [Why do messages posted by PostThreadMessage disappear?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090930-00/?p=16553) if you are looking to implement a reliable solution.